# Using php file() function to put a html or php file into array

Tags: php, fwrite

When I try to use the php file() function like:

in a test.php:

```
$lines = file("./folder/page.php");
foreach ($lines as $line ) {
    echo $line;
}
```

page.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>   
<div class="about">
    About: 

</div>
<div class="question">
    Question: 

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It returns,

```
 About:
 Question:
```

And no html tags, no php lines. 
Goal, to have an array $lines with all the info as in the texteditor.

Comment: Please post content of page.php

Comment: If you open page.php in a browser what do you see?  Same thing right?  View source in browser.

Comment: When you say "it returns", where is that? Did you check the source code? HTML tags are usually invisible in the browser...

Comment: What are the contents of your PHP File? If your PHP File should  be generating the content, your code will not interpret them. It will just echo them back: 1-2-1. Try the same with an arbitrary HTML File and see that you get exactly what you had expected.

Comment: @Poiz I think I got it. How do I see the arraylines, Like something as $lines[4] -> "<body>"

Comment: instead of echo use: var_dump like so:  **$lines = file(__DIR__ ."/./folder/page.php");
 foreach ($lines as $line ) {
  var_dump( $line );
 }**

Comment: @Webomatik ye it returns in the browser, I know.. stupid, I should have seen that.

Comment: @Poiz Thanks,      -

Comment: var_dump says "string(2)" "string(8)" ... etc "About:"
no relationship that I see with the length of the tags or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine. 
You are probably viewing your output on a browser which assumes that the HTML tags are a part of the page. If you view the page source you'll see that you get the desired output. 
So escape your HTML characters you'll get your output just fine.

```
$lines = file("page.php");
foreach ($lines as $line ) {
    echo htmlentities($line)."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to your what you asked me, try this:

```
$arrLines   = array();
$lines      = file("./folder/page.php");

foreach ($lines as $line ) {
    $arrLines[] = $line;
}
var_dump($arrLines);
```